# Image download and cache (in memory or disk) with Libgdx

Tags: android, image, http, libgdx

I use Libgdx to develop a UI on Android (only on Android), and need to show lots of web images.
In native Android, I use the [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to manage and cache images.

Anyone have suggestions for Libgdx-based solutions?

I'm using the [Libgdx Net HTTP API](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=7146).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the Android Universal Image Loader with Libgdx.  Any of its image "display" routines will not work, but the code to download and cache images should (?) be fine (when used by your project's Android backend).

Look at the Libgdx doc for working with "platform-specific" libraries and APIs: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific

I haven't looked too closely at the Loader's code, so this may be a dead end if the display code is too entangled with the rest.

Comment: I use : com.badlogic.gdx.Net, with apache httpclient in android backend. i will try Android Universal Image Loader.